# How can I underline marked text to differentiate the text from the pointer?

Tags: emacs

When I first installed the solarized-theme and set the recommended values for variables [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs). There was the great effect of marked text being vertically longer than my cursor which made it easier to see where the cursor was. I'm not sure if it was the effect of setting

```
(setq x-underline-at-descent-line t)
```

but after customizing the colors of the theme a bit more, I lost the effect of what I saw before anymore (can't seem to revert to it after reinstalling the theme either). So the effect I meant was marking a region (highlighting text) would highlight from the Capline down to the Baseline.

[image: Marked character]

Sometimes I get it when I just start up emacs. Here is one of the lucky times I was about to get it.

[image]

Here you can see that the marked region is going from the topline to bottomline.

**EDIT:** After accidentally getting it to work again. I think I only get this desired effect on org headers on the 1st/top level. How can I get this effect everywhere?

Comment: FWIW, it's not clear to me what you mean by "marked text" and "vertically longer than my cursor". I have no idea what appearance you liked that you can no longer get.

Comment: @Drew Sorry about that, I clarified the question some more. By marked text I just meant text that was in a marked region or in non-emacs terms, just highlighted text. I was by chance able to get the desired effect I wanted again but it only has that effect on org 1st level headers and I want to expand it to all text.

Comment: I have never seen `:background` highlighting from the *baseline* to the *capline*.  For the past two years I have used Emacs, it has always highlighted from the bottomline to the topline.  Your best bet may be to choose a `default` font where the letters actually reach the bottomline and topline.  Other ideas include making your cursor a different color than the highlighted region -- e.g., cursor color is a yellow and you control the thickness, and region highlighting can be a see-through gray color.  If you once found it working, it was probably because you found a font that was very tall.

Comment: @lawlist The same font is used for the org header as all the other text and I can't get this behavior when highlighting from right to left, it only happens from marking left to right. When highlighting normal text I can't get that behavior either and I think they're the same font (just different size). My thoughts is that there is variable (setting) somewhere that controls this but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: The effect you describe would be more noticeable if something *somewhere* on the line is taller than the regular font.  For example, certain unicode characters may be taller than the font currently being used, and that will cause the *whole line* to be taller -- consequently making the highlighted region taller.  For example, I love this checkmark ✓ but I can't use it because it makes my whole line taller.  Perhaps that peace symbol is the cause of the behavior -- or perhaps it is that circle.  If you get rid of the peace symbol and if you get rid of that circle, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @lawlist but even if you highlight the same **word** as in the picture and only that word but this time from right to left instead of left to right, the behavior in the picture will  **not** happen. There will be no extra cursor, the marked region looks like normal. So I don't think the circle matters (that's from org-bullet mode) or its a font issue either.

Comment: I suspect that this is only happening because the character before the comma is coming from a separate font, causing the entire line to have a bigger height than normal.

Comment: @Chris Actually I can get the same effect on org headers that have just english characters, but it is most likely the giant circle on the far left that comes from Org Bullets mode (as lawlist mentioned previously)...I turned org bullets mode off and couldn't get the same effect at all so I think this is probably the cause. It'd be great if the marked region could be extended to as in the diagram topline to bottomline while the cursor is Capline to Baseline but that's beyond my emacs lisp ability